# Entity Framework mistakes composite key with some varchar columns as identity

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Col1] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [col3] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [col4] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Col5] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Col6] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Col7] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [Col8] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
    [Col9] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [MyTable$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Col1] ASC,
    [Col2] ASC,
    [Col3] ASC,
    [Col4] ASC,
    [Col5] ASC,
    [Col6] ASC,
    [Col7] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
```

I use the EF Generator to clreate the MyTable class, set all the fields and save changes.  I get the following error:

> Store-generated keys are only
>   supported for identity columns. Key
>   column 'Col2' has type
>   'SqlServer.varchar', which is not a
>   valid type for an identity column.

What I don't understand is why it thinks it is an identity column.  How would I fix that error? Am I looking in the right direction?

Comment: If you check properties of Col2 in your entity model what is the value for Store generated pattern?

Comment: I really don't see why this question is tagged with `asp.net` and `asp.net-mvc-2`. Absolutely no relation. It's a totally EF specific question.

Comment: The Store Generated Pattern value is set to 'None'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the error message is irrelevant.  What it should say is something about non-nullable PK values.  It seems that one of the values involved in the PK was null.  I think this problem has to do with the String type in C# being nullable, since Nullable was set to False in the EF Designer and did not throw an error since it was simply not being set.

Comment: Also, the answer to this question could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381500/entity-framework-savechanges-error-details

Comment: I have encountered this exact issue a few times now with EF 4, the error message is very misleading. Thanks for posting this answer, you saved me a few hours of banging my head on the desk.